# How should I go about fixing build errors?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, xcode7-beta4

Should I fix my build errors as soon as I get them ? Or should I (let's say) try to fix all of my errors every week or so ? Or should I just code the majority of my app and then try to fix all the errors ?

In other words, how often should I be trying to fix all of my build errors ?

Comment: I find it's easier to fix errors as soon as they happen, as you will not be able to build your project if any errors are present. I also try to keep any warnings to a minimum as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consistently try and fix errors as you find/create them, and focus on making a compiling and running application with each individual change you do.

If you are using version control, focus on making each change set a running application, even if some of your stuff isn't finished yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: You should also fix warnings immedeatly because the more warnings you have the sooner you will overlook the warnings which are really important.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, my personal rule is that I don't allow a commit with errors in it. Normally I'll make a commit when I finish a feature or portion of a feature. After I finish roughing out a feature, I'll "cleanup". This is where I format my code, optimize things, and remove warnings.